# Ubuntu doesn't suspend when battery is low

Tags: suspend, battery

I'm using Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 on a Labtop. Even if org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power seems to be correct, ubuntu doesn't suspend or shutdown when battery is low. Not good, computer can be damaged when battery is empty.

If I switch use-time-for-policy to false, same issue, nothing happen when battery is low/critical. I tested up to 3% of battery. I have about 4h of battery.

Please, could you tell me how to fix it in order to suspend or shutdown when battery is low (10%). Thanks.

Here is my parameters for settings-daemon.plugins.power :

```
gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-power 'shutdown'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-timeout 3600
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power power-button-action 'nothing'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power critical-battery-action 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power percentage-low 10
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power priority 0
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-suspend-with-external-monitor true
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-dim true
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-hibernate 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-suspend 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-sleep 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-timeout 900
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power time-low 1200
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-ac-action 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power notify-perhaps-recall true
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power percentage-critical 8
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power percentage-action 6
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-battery-type 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power time-action 300
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-battery-action 'suspend'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-brightness 30
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power ambient-enabled true
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power time-critical 800
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power active true
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power use-time-for-policy true
```

Comment: Does a hardware or system problem?

Comment: No suspend, no shutdown when battery low.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably a bug of Ubuntu of hardware support. Finally, I used the following script to suspend ubuntu when battery is low :
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/289129

Comment: I don't think that's it as Dell XPS is pretty well supported yet it suspends, resumes, suspends when battery is critically low. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1395258